# Unittest API calls in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Can anyone suggest a how to perform unit test(s) against a method which has an API call in it?

My xamarin application has rest call as follows:

```cs
var result = await Rest.Get(uri)  
 .WithTrackingIndicator(RestCall.GetChecklistHistoryByStorage)  
 .WithConnectivityPrecheck(true, res => { res.ResultObject = new ChecklistList { Checklist = _checklistMapper.Map(_checklistStorageService.Find(instanceIdentifier, StorageKeyType.PrimaryKey), true) }; })   
 .ExecuteAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you abstract your API call behind an interface then you can Mock the behaviour with a framework such as [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4)

Something like this:

```
public interface IRest
{
    Task<Result> Get(Uri uri);
}
```

Then you could set something up like:

```
var restMock = new Mock<IRest>();

restMock(rest => rest.Get(uri))
      .Returns(new Result());
```

There will obviously be some further complexities getting around your `WithTrackingIndicator` and `WithConnectivityPrecheck` methods but this should hopefully give you a good starting point.